# float and double types in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, floating-point

I am learning C++ in 11th standard. I don't have much knowledge about C++

In my college, there is visual studio 2005. I have a project to convert celsius to farenheit. This code works fine in my college in visual studio 2005:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   float f,cs;

    cin>>cs;
    cout<<"\n celsius = "<<cs;
    f=1.8*cs+32.0;
    cout<<"f = "<<f;
}
```

But when I run this code in visual studio 2012 after modifying:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   float f,cs;

   cin>>cs;
   cout<<"\n cs = "<<cs;
   f=1.8*cs+32.0;
   cout<<"f = "<<f;
}
```

It gives me following errors:

> conversion from double to float possible

Comment: Notice that the `main()` function should have signature `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. `void main()` is non-standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a warning, as you multiply 1.8 (which is a `double` literal) with `cs`, yielding a `double`. In C++, if you have an expression with two different types, a *type promotion* is performed to the type with the largest value range; for `double` and `float` this means that `cs` is converted to `double`. This is then assigned to a `float`, which might not be able to represent the full value range of `double` (`float` is a 32-bit IEEE floating point number, `double` is 64-bit.) Hence the warning.

You can fix this by writing:

```
f=1.8f*cs+32.0f;
```

or by changing `f` to be of type `double`.

Note: Your code is compiling, this is just a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an error, it's a warning. Your code still compiles. It's warning you that you have some value of type `double` that you're trying to squish into a `float`. The reason it's occurring is because floating point literals (such as `1.8` and `32.0`) are of type `double` by default. Multiplying a `double` by a `float` gives you a `double`, so the result of `1.8*cs+32.0` is therefore of type `double`. If you want `float`s, you must do `1.8f` and `32.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:`f=1.8*cs+32.0;` you are using floating-point constants, which default to type `double`.
You need to use floating-suffix `f` to specify it's `float`: `f = 1.8f * cs + 32.0f;`

See [C++ Floating-Point Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfh6f0w2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)